# How to keep multiple subwindows open in Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, electron, chromium, window.open

My app structure overview:

- Main window (loaded via [`win.loadURL`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window/#winloadurlurl-options), has no access to [`electron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron)).

  - Five subwindows opened via [`window.open(url, '_blank')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Currently, when opening multiple subwindows, the later opened will replace the former opened, how to keep them all open, instead of replacing each other?

Comment: What do your `window.open` call look like exactly? Are you passing in the same window name each time?

Comment: @pushkin They are all in the form of `window.open(url, '_blank')`. I tried giving them different window names after reading your comment, but that didn't succeed.

Comment: hm, that shouldn't be happening. Did you enable `nativeWindowOpen: true` in your main window?

Comment: @pushkin Thanks! After specifying `nativeWindowOpen: true`, the subwindows can be kept all open, you can post an answer for this.

Comment: @pushkin Also, it works even if the window names are all `_blank`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: in Electron 15, `nativeWindowOpen` defaults to `true`.

---

You should enable `nativeWindowOpen` on your main window.

```js
new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { nativeWindowOpen: true } })
```

Then, each `window.open` call (assuming you aren't using the same window name, not counting special window names like `'_blank'`) will open a brand new window.